# Is there a way of exiting Google Translate's iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-translate

In our website we have a link that allows people to view the page using Google Translate, e.g. https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=fr&js=n&prev=_t&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com. Google Translate wraps our page in an iframe and does its magic.

We open this link in a new tab. Once the user has finished we'd like to provide an easy way for the user to get back to what they were doing. They can close the tab themselves, but their focus is on the content rather than on browser controls. Is there any way for us to provide a button on the page that will close the tab? I'm thinking something like `window.close()` would do for a normal tab.

Comment: `top.close()` would close the tab the iframe is in.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Nope, I just get: 'Blocked a frame with origin "..." from accessing a cross-origin frame.'